# Game won't sign into Google Play Games

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am developing a game where you should automatically connect to Google Play Games if you are signed in on your phone. However, when starting the app it tries to login and a "loading wheel" comes up for a few seconds. Then it shuts down and nothing happens, it failed to connect.

In Unity I have a keystore where I obtain a SHA-1 certificate. This is the same which is found in Google Play Console under app signing and Upload Key Certificate.
Then in API OAuth and Credentials I have a Production keystore where I put in the same SHA-1 certificate, which it tells you to do.

In Unity on start up I use the following code to authenticate:

```
void Awake()
    {

        // Set up the Play Service Configuration
        ClientConfiguration = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(ClientConfiguration);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        // Authenticate the player and log into Play Games
        DoAuthenticate(SignInInteractivity.CanPromptAlways);
    }

internal void DoAuthenticate(SignInInteractivity interactivity)
{
    
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(interactivity, (code) =>
    {
        if (code == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Authenticated. Hello, " + Social.localUser.userName + " (" + Social.localUser.id + ")");
            isAuthenticated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("*** Failed to authenticate with " + code);
            isAuthenticated = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine when in debug mode and installing phone locally on the phone. Why is it not working when released to Play Store? Am I missing something?